# Seamless video loop in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, video, video-streaming

I'm using Strobe Media Player (https://sourceforge.net/adobe/smp/home/Strobe%20Media%20Playback/) in order to play some mp4 videos and I would like each video to autoloop once it finishes playing. The Media Player has such an option (loop=true) but the looping is really glitchy (i.e. after the video ends there is a very noticeable 500ms+ pause during which the last frame is shown).

What can I do about this?

Since the media player is open source I downloaded its source and found the code responsible for the looping. I added a timer that is fired each 20ms and checks if there are less than 25ms left before the video ends and I do `seek(0)` in this case (this was a suggested approach from some blog - seek to the beginning before the video ends so that it doesn't freeze) but it was to no avail.

How can I autoloop the played video smoothly?

Comment: Do you need any features like timeline seeking? If not, and want just looping playback, then you can use the `appendBytes` API of Netstream. It expects FLV format only but this tool [**Codec-AS3**](https://github.com/minosss/codec-as3) will remux (cut/paste) the h.264 video codec from MP4 and put into empty FLV shell. Then you feed the new FLV bytes to decoder. When you get a "buffer empty"  just re-append the bytes... gives seamless looping.

Comment: Good answer, but small comment: don't wait till buffer empty. Feed before it.